# HTML - Links and ID

Tags: html

I have a [website](http://www.prova.it) in which, the HTML code I have a nav menu like this:

```
<a href="#section1"> blabla </ a>
```

and in this special section:

```
<p id="section1"> blabla </ p>
```

Because when I press 'blabla' in the URL does not come as `www.prova.it/ # section1` but only as `www.prova.it`?

Comment: Are you sure you're pressing the right 'blabla'?

Comment: See for yourself, try changing sections .. the URL is not changed.. 'mobshop.altervista.org'

Comment: The code posted does not reproduce the problem. And server www.prova.it does not exist; do not use real-looking domain names unless they are ready. Regarding the URL mentioned in the comment, you should minimally include it in the question but preferably analyze the page and try to reduce the problems to a simple case so that you can include the *code* in the question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes, it works!

When you click on a hyperlink with some element's id, then the browser moves you (scrolls you) to the element!

So, this link `<a href="#section1">blabla</a>` will always move the browser to the location of the element!

#### For your information

For your information: One HTML DOM can have only one element with a specified ID, so in your document you can add `#section1` to only one element and other elements must have a seperate id!

#### What is wrong; what might be

Your elements are perfect! The hyperlink will take the client (user) to the location of the element. The only problem that you might be encountering would be

1. Wrong ID or wrong element being clicked!
2. Element and the hyperlink in the same page, and no scrolling space!
   This type of error generally comes up, when the document is singled paged, and the browser cannot scroll the document anymore! So you won't be able to see any change in the scroll!

#### Here is the code of yours

Here is the code of yours: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/5e7TF/

I just added some margins for the `p` as

```
#section1 {
  margin: 500px;
}
```

And when I clicked on the link, it moved the browser down!

#### What might be causing the URL not to change

Now the error in your page, why it isn't changing the URL, is because you are using either

```
return false;
```

Or this one:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

By which the URL stays the same!

#### Try this for remedy

So, try this one:

```
$('a[href="#section1"]'.click(function () { // jQuery
   history.pushState('', 'Page Name', '#section1');
}
```

#### Example for `history.pushState`

You can test this one here: http://html5.gingerhost.com Try to load some new pages.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` is not jQuery specific. It's the `event` object as well as the `preventDefault()` is native JavaScript.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for this false information, but I started my development journey from jQuery so I don't know much of pure Javascript and thanks for correction Sir! :)

Comment: I have updated the answer! :) Thnks for information..@MadaraUchiha